# Why files are created with different encodings using vi

Tags: files, character-encoding

When I work with Bash scripts, I always create files using `vi`.

I am debugging a script that in theory is written correcly and I decided to check the files I have created using the `file` command. This is what I see.

```
myScript1  Bourne-Again shell script text executable, Unicode text, UTF-8 text
myScript2  ASCII text
myScript3  POSIX shell script text executable, ASCII text
myScript4  Unicode text, UTF-8 text
```

How can four scripts created on the same day by `vi` have different encodings?

The one I am debugging is `ASCII text`

How do a change this to `Bourne-Again shell script text executable, Unicode text, UTF-8 text`?

Comment: `file` just gueses the type of a file based on its content. So we'd need to see something of the content of these files. The shebang (`#!`) line at very start of a file may be different and `file` will read a different type of shell script. Also the difference between ASCII text and UTF-8 text may simply be if there are any multi-byte characters in it (character codes > 127). File must guess the difference between UFT-8 and ASCII because there is no actual difference between the bytes. But if no character codes > 127 are found then ASCII and UTF-8 are identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file` just gueses the type of a file based on its content. We'd need to see something of the content of these files.

At a guess of what's happening:

The two different types of script may be caused by different shebang (`#!`) line at very start of a file.

The difference between ASCII text and UTF-8 text may simply be if there are any multi-byte characters in it (character codes > 127). File must guess the difference between UFT-8 and ASCII because there is no actual difference between the bytes.

But if no character codes > 127 are found then ASCII and UTF-8 are identical.

Comment: you are right. THANKS!